# Samsung WebApi.js not Working on Tizen TV-Samsung-4.0 Emulator

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

The Tizen samsung-tv-4.0 emulator is not running the apps properly. I am getting the error:

$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Does the samsung-tv-4.0 emulator not support the web apis? What's the difference from the simulator then?

When I used Tizen Studio v.2.0 and TV extension v.3.0, it was working, but now It's not.

I even created a template project for tv-samsung-4.0, and added  in index.html, but the error appears in the WebInspector

Who has the problem? Help me.

Comment: Did you explicitly add the script tag into your application entrypoint html? The API can be available globally in some cases, but some APIs won't be available unless you explicitly import the script.

Comment: Yes, all about this is fine. Try to create a template project and insert `webapis.js` and you'll get the error in the WebInspector's console. It seems that the new version of Tizen Studio doesn't support `webapis.js`
On the tizen.org https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/does-simulator-tizen-studio-2.1-support-webapis